# How can I list all databases with Squirrel SQL?

Tags: sql, squirrel-sql, sqltools

Squirrel SQL would become my favourite SQL tool if only it would have one function:
I need to connect to one and only database (alias) and I need to define it manually.

Can I connect to all databases or at least browse the databases on server and create aliases automatically. Now I need to know database name to connect to it...

Does anyone know a solution/tip for that?

Comment: This is possible for some DBMSs and not others. (It is easy with MariaDB. I have tried and failed with PostgreSQL. I can't think of a way it would even make sense to do it with SQLite. I am told it works for SQL Server but not Azure SQL Database.)  It may also depend on which driver you are using (for example, xerial/sqlite-jdbc ,  jdbc.postgresql.org , downloads.mariadb.org/client-java/ , jtds.sourceforge.net )  If you tell us more about your databases, we may be able to find an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily from the GUI. After you open your session, click the Objects tab, then expand the tree. Expand the db, schema, and then table nodes, and you'll see all of your tables. If you click on a particular table node, a table will open to the right. By clicking the Columns tab, you can get the column names, types, and other meta data.

See here: [How can I list all tables in a database with Squirrel SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4896613/how-can-i-list-all-tables-in-a-database-with-squirrel-sql)

Answer (score 0):

From GUI i think it's not possible, since you must specify a database in connection URL (for postgres),  Postgres (and i think others DB TOO),  if there is a way to connect without specifying a database i could be possible

Answer (score 0):

The maximum no of rows that can be visible is 90000.

goto

> file--> New Session Properties--> Object Tree--> Contents-limit row

and specify the no of row limit and restart the application.