# can't see tables in SQuirrel

Tags: hsqldb, squirrel-sql

I am using a HSQL driver to connect to my database.  I am able to connect without any errors but I can't see any of my tables in the table tree under public.  I am able to create new tables which do appear, but I can't see the already created ones.  Also when I check the .script file I can't see the new tables.  Something strange is going on but I can’t work out what.

Anyone able to help.

Answer (score 2):

I've worked it out now.  It was the format of the connect string for HSQL.

I needed to add :file: in the string like this... jdbc:hsqldb:file:

Also I was using .script at the end of the file name, like this jdbc:hsqldb:.script

This was creating temp files in the format .script.lck .script.log etc.

Dropping the .script at the end of the file name opened up the database and allowed me to see the tables.  Now my problem is I can't get any updates to commit. Updates happen with no errors in the console.  But when I close the file and check the .script file the data is the same.  Permissions I guess.

Only posting this answer to help others that might get stuck at the same point.

Answer (score 0):

Try here:
[How can I list all tables in a database with Squirrel SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4896613/how-can-i-list-all-tables-in-a-database-with-squirrel-sql/21049974#21049974)

Where most of us fails is to choose the right schema in the Catalog dropdown. (Just above the Objects tab). But there are other ideas if you follow the related question.